# How to run code only once when internet connection is available again?

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I want to run some code only once when the User has internet access again.

My first thought was using a BroadcastReceiver on "Android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" and unregister it right after the code was run. But I realized that this will also run the code when the user deactivates the internet connection.

Is there a better way? Or is there a way to check if the current intent was a deactivation or an activation of the internet connection?

This is how it looks currently:

```
final BroadcastReceiver OnConnecion = new BroadcastReceiver() {
                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                    if(isOnline()){
                        vplan1 = new Vplan("vplan1", CheckService.this);
                        vplan2 = new Vplan("vplan2", CheckService.this);
                        Calendar heute = Calendar.getInstance();
                        Calendar date1 = vplan1.getCalendar();
                        Calendar date2 = vplan2.getCalendar();
                        if ((!(vergleiche(heute, date1) < 0)) & (!(vergleiche(heute, date2) < 0))) {
                            getData task = new getData();               
                            task.execute();
                            unregisterReceiver(this);
                        }

                    }
                }
            };
            registerReceiver(OnConnecion, new IntentFilter("android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"));
```

Thanks

Comment: You need to check the NetworkInfo thought the ConnectivityManager since CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE only informs that something has changed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are Familiar with SharedPreferences, The Answer would be Easy.

First. Put these Permissions in Your Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Then, Please Create a Structure Like Below, And you should be Good to go:

```js
public class activity extends AppCompatActivity {

  Context mContext;
  private boolean OnlyOneTime;


  @Override
  protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    this = mContext;



    SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);
    SharedPreferences.Editor prefEdit = pref.edit();

    OnlyOneTime = pref.getBoolean("One_time", true);

    try {

      if (OnlyOneTime) {


        // Put Your Code that Uses Internet Connection And Must Only happen One Time 
      }

    } catch (Exception e) {
      prefEdit.putBoolean("One_time", false);
      prefEdit.apply();

      e.printStackTrace();
    }

  }
}
```

This Has an EXCEPTION in it. You don't need to Any Network Class at all.

If The Download fails, It will Throws an Exception.

Now if You Want This to be Repeaded. Just Add:

```
prefEdit.putBoolean("One_time", true);
prefEdit.apply();
```

Anywhere You Want. And Repeat The Process.